# warning: Unclosed files for the types when debugging with RealmObject model

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

This is the first time that I've tried using Realm as a local datastore and I'm getting a compilation error that I don't understand. I haven't been able to see any reference for this error anywhere else. What is going on?

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import io.realm.RealmObject
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey
import io.realm.annotations.RealmClass

@RealmClass
open class DeviceItem(

        @PrimaryKey var id: Long = 0,
        var device: BluetoothDevice? = null,
        var deviceName: String= "",
        var address: String = "",
        connected: String = ""

) : RealmObject() {

    var connected: Boolean = false
        set

    init {
        this.connected = connected === "true"
    }

}
```

**Error:**

```
warning: Unclosed files for the types '[io.realm.ca_test_test_DeviceItemRealmProxy]'; these types will not undergo annotation processing
```

Comment: It's not clear at all, tbh :p

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I think it's complaining about ``var device: BluetoothDevice? = null,`` which references a Data object. I don't think you can store those in Realm. I removed it and I no longer got that error but I also got a whole bunch of other errors and since then realized Realm won't solve my problem anyway so I removed it from my app.

Comment: It is actually a surprise that it compiled at all, that is indeed not a supported field type. Would need `@Ignore` to be ignored, but that of course means it is not persisted (and each RealmProxy realm gives you is a new instance so that can make things tricky)